# Can RevSlider be configured Programatically (PHP)?

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

I am trying to figure out if RevSlider can be used to build slides programatically. I tried to ask on their support site but they have no way for pre-sales questions to be asked... considering they require a serial for registering.

What I need to do is build a slider than I can have a cron job that will update the slider with dynamic content. This is inside a WordPress installation but the cron will be fetching data from a third-party solution. What I need to do is use the data from the third-party to build each slide every night.

I am using a Custom Post Type, as RevSlider can handle this, and I have a custom taxonomy used for grouping the data that is to be presented. I have used RevSlider before but I do not believe it can handle my needs for this project.

The scope is to have a slider that is shown for 2 mins. Ideally, it will have 3 slides and each slide will need to have content added to it from the post type. The amount of data per slide will vary but I will need to have multiple types of data per slide. I will need to add this data VIA PHP as having someone do this every night is not possible.

So I am asking, can RevSlider be configured using PHP? Can I add slides and content with PHP into the slider?

P.S. I tried to see if a question like this was against the rules but I could not even find the rules for questions on this site...

Answer (score 0):

I have used rev slider to dynamically display content.  And my crown job changes the status of 3/10 images inside my db.  So in my presentation layer,  every 30 mins the slides change.You just have to put the paths correctly in the tags....in WordPress I think it would be in a echo statement so just chain(concatenate) the path there to the echo statement